# Cannot print a table with *ngFor from a json

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

This particular Json **does not have** the **key** of each element in the arrays, I managed to make this work with other Jsons which bring the element keys and use those keys in the {{data.key}} to print with *ngFor.

I tried more than 25 solutions in stackoverflow but it seems that my case is unique, no one else uses a JSON without **keys/labels** to create a table.

This is my Json:

```
{
    "data": {
        "spnf": {
            "anios": [
                "2018-Q4",
                "2018-Q4"
            ],
            "titulos": [
                "Ingresos Totales",
                "Balance Total"
            ],
            "anioactual": [
                3183,
                -837
            ],
            "anioanterior": [
                3672,
                1549
            ]
        },
        "gob_central": {
            "anios": [
                "2018-Q4",
                "2018-Q4"
            ],
            "titulos": [
                "Ingresos Totales",
                "Balance Total"
            ],
            "anioactual": [
                3183,
                -837
            ],
            "anioanterior": [
                3672,
                1549
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is my balances.ts:

```
{

    this.loader.present().then(() => {
      this.finanzaService.getBalances2()
        .subscribe((result) => {
          this.dataRequest = result;
          this.setData();
          // Disable Loader
          this.loader.dismiss();
        }, (err) => {
          "error blah blah"
        }
        );
    });
  }

public setData(tipo: string = 'spnf') {

  if (tipo == 'spnf') {
    this.dataResumen = _.clone(this.dataRequest.spnf);
  } else {
    this.dataResumen = _.clone(this.dataRequest.gob_central);
  }
}
```

This is my finanzapublica.service.ts:

```
 public getBalances2(): Observable<any>{
  const url = `${this.apiURL}/balances_fiscales/balances_datos2.json`;
  return this.http.get(url, this.options)
    .map((res: Response) =>  res.json().data);
}
```

This is my balances.html, as soon as I try this.dataResumen, the app breaks and throws error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

```
          <table *ngIf="dataRequest">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td class="border" text-center>Rubro</td>
                <td class="border" *ngFor="let data of this.dataResumen.anios" text-center>{{ data }}</td> <!--this works-->
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let data of this.dataResumen"><!--this doesn't work-->
             <td class="border" text-center>{{data.titulos}}</td>
             <td class="border" text-center>{{data.anioactual}}</td>
             <td class="border" text-center>{{data.anioanterior}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

This is the error:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '{
  "anios": [
    "2018-Q4",
    "2018-Q4"
  ],
  "titulos": [
    "Ingresos Totales",
    "Balance Total"
  ],
  "anioactual": [
    3183,
    -837
  ],
  "anioanterior": [
    3672,
    1549
  ]
}' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

The result I wanted is like:

```
Rubros             2018-Q4       2018-Q4
Ingresos Totales     3183         3672
Balance Total        -837         1549
```

Comment: Can you try putting {{data.dataResumen|json}} and show is what you get

Comment: Hi @PariBaker I just edited the post and added the error with the | json

Comment: what is the result of console.log(this.dataRasumen) after it gets its data?

Comment: @PariBaker result is : dataResumen {anios: Array(2), titulos: Array(19), anioactual: Array(19), anioanterior: Array(19)}

Comment: I might be slightly confused on what the end result would look like but here is what I have on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdtk4v

Comment: Updated it so each value goes to its own td

Comment: thank for taking the time to do this @PariBaker , but do you see on my balances.ts how I use _.clone in order to have a button to get SPNF and other for GOB_CENTRAL,  do you think this _.clone is the cause of my problem?

Comment: check the stackblitz I used lodash clone and i get the same result. That's why Im asking what the result you expect it

Comment: sure @PariBaker, the result I expect is a <tr ngfor> that gets:  <td>titulos</td> <td>anioactual</td><td>anioanterior</td>

Comment: Ah so you want a row of keys not a row for each key

Comment: @PariBaker there, I just edited my post and placed the result I expected, I really apreciate all your help.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdtk4v this gets the table you want but not very dynamic, I would suggest you instead transform the data you get from the get request. So where you have the map and you return the data instead

Comment: depending on which version of angular (new one takes pipe) .get.pipe(.map(res=>{return res.map(item=>{return{ --transformed object--  } })}))

Comment: hi @PariBaker it worked !!  actually the solution was to use the let i= index as you did, I left the rest of my code the same way, only added the index and it worked as a charm, thank you very much, you can post the index as the answer

Comment: so it worked as it is on stackblitz now?

Comment: @PariBaker yes, the solution was to use the ngFor index, to place each element on each TD in the loop.

Comment: Great, good to hear thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
        <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td class="border" text-center>Rubro</td>
                <td class="border" *ngFor="let data of dataResumen?.anios" text-center>{{ data }}</td> <!--this works-->
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let data of dataResumen.titulos; let i=index;">
                {{data}}
                <td>{{dataResumen.anioactual[i]}}</td>
                 <td>{{dataResumen.anioanterior[i]}}</td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
```